# JAX-RS: How can I return my list of objects as JSON?

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs

I looked at the documentation of [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes), and it left me confused :(
My entity looks like  :

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "variable")
 public class Variable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private VariableType type;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String units;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_on", nullable = false)
    private Date createdOn;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "retired_on", nullable = true)
    private Date retiredOn;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean core;

}
```

and my `JAX-RS` service looks like

```
@Path("/variable")
public class VariableResource {
    @Inject private VariableManager variableManager;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getVariables() {
        return Response.ok(variableManager.getVariables()).build();
    }

}
```

When I test this service using `curl http://localhost:8080/app/rest/variable`, I see the following in my server logs

```
[javax.ws.rs.core.Application]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) Servlet.service() for servlet javax.ws.rs.core.Application threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
```

What are some simplest ways I can return my list of variables as JSON?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Normally it is as simple as adding the `@XmlRootElement` on your Entity (I can see you're using JPA/Hibernate `@Entity`/`@Table`, but you're missing the `@XmlRootElement`).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "variable")
@XmlRootElement
public class Variable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    // ...

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean core;
}
```

And this is for the service, using the `Response` from JAX-RS, and also returning directly an object that will be marshaled automatically by JAX-RS:

```
@Path("/variable")
public class VariableResource {
    @Inject private VariableManager variableManager;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getVariables() {
        return Response.ok(variableManager.getVariables()).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    // Same method but without using the JAX-RS Response object
    public List<Variable> getVariablesAlso() {
        return variableManager.getVariables();
    }
}
```

Often people would create a [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) to avoid exposing internal values of the Entity from the database to the real world, but it is not mandatory, if it is fine for you to expose the whole object.

Comment: and would it also work if I need to map/serialize data from user to @Entity?

Comment: If you want JAX-RS to output JSON from an entity, the entity should have the `@XmlRootElement`. Now if a method of your resource service takes an element of type `Variable` as a post parameter, JAX-RS will create the object for you and it will be possible to save it via any `Repository`/`EntityManager` (it's just an object after all, and it does have the `@Entity` annotation).

Comment: One clarification: `@XmlRootElement` is not required by JAX-RS, but by JAXB, if it is being used. And for JSON it often is not (it is used for XML output by default however). Adding that won't hurt of course, and may be safer to ensure XML output works. But just thought I'd point it out for sake of completeness.